# How do I listen for a button click in Javascript and trigger a custom php function in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've added a button to the Woocommerce order page

```
//function to add button
function action_woocommerce_order_create_csf_order_button( $order ){
echo '<button type="button" class="button" name="create-order-csf">' . __( 'Create CSF Order', 'csf-delivery' ) . '</button>';
};

// add new button for woocommerce
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons', 'action_woocommerce_order_create_csf_order_button', 10, 1);
```

The result is the following:

[Results of executing the Above Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIZp0.png)

When the button is clicked it should trigger function which would make a call to an external API.

I've searched what feels like the entire web and cannot figure out how to trigger a php function using this button. I'm new to plugin development and any assistance would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

So based on the comments below I would need to listen for the button click using Javascript and trigger the php function using that.

I would appreciate some direction in doing this.

Comment: That hook will only create the button, you'll need to add the JS code to trigger any desired action.

Comment: @Skatox just to clarify you mean I need to add JS to listen for the button click and then send it back to WordPress to execute the php function?

Comment: Exactly that. That’s the easier way.

Comment: @Skatox ok thanks for clarifying, would you happen to have any resources I can check out?

Comment: If you refomulate the question I can give you an answer.

Comment: @Skatox i edited the question please let me know if that is fine

Comment: You should probably set up a proper AJAX endpoint for this, that is the cleanest way IMHO. https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins, https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/